# Wordpress list parent-page and children / parent-title not showing on parent-page

Tags: php, wordpress

currently i am using this code to print a list of a parent-page and its children.

```
        <?php
        if($post->post_parent){
            $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&include=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0"); 
            $children .= wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
        } else {
            $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&include=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
            $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
        }
        if ($children) { ?>
        <div class="meta-box">
            <div class="nav-right">
              <ul>
                <?php echo $children; ?>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <?php } ?>
```

Everything works fine when i am on a child page. It prints the title of the parent page and the titles of its children.

But when i am on a parent page it only prints the children and not the title of the parent page.

What i want to achieve:

When on parent page:

- Parent title (currently not showing)
- Child 1
- Child 2
- Child 3

When on child page:

- Parent title
- Child 1
- Child 2
- Child 3

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Mat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine, you are missing a period in the 'else' rule

```
<?php
        if($post->post_parent){
            $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&include=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0"); 
            $children .= wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
        } else {
            $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&include=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
            $children .= wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
        }
        if ($children) { ?>
        <div class="meta-box">
            <div class="nav-right">
              <ul>
                <?php echo $children; ?>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: You sir deserve a medal. I was looking for hours and couldnt find the error.
Problem solved, thanks a lot!